# Display an image in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am making a app and part of it needs to display an image. Instead of have the app download the image, I want to just show it in a UIWebView. I have added the WebView to the app and given it the URL to the image and told it to load, however it stays as a white screen. I even tried to get it to load www.google.com and it still wouldn't load.

Can anyone help me with this? Here is how everything I'm doing to the web view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requent = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

The webView is declared as follows in the .h file:

```
IBOUTlet UIWebView *webView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
```

And it is synthesised in the .m file.

Comment: did you check your connection of webView in XIB ?

Comment: What is it meant to be connected to? and I am using xcode4 so it's a storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `www.google.com` with `http://www.google.com` and it will work.

Please also add UIWebView as IBOutlet -

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

please connect web view in your story board -

[image]

[image]

Comment: then most probably you didn't connect your webview in story board.

Comment: when I click and drag to there, the only thing that comes up is delegate... there is no view or webView... does this mean I didn't declare it properly?

Comment: you are dragging from webview to viewcontroller, reverse it drag from viewcontroller to webview and you will get it

Answer (score 1):

Your .H file should look like this.

```
@interface slTableViewController () {
IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
```

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *myWebView;
of course this will mean you'll have to add @synthesize myWebView; to your .m file!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly bind your webView's delegate. Add this **UIWebViewDelegate** in .h of  ViewController

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Now go to **xib** of ViewController and right click to it it show **delegate** and **drag to fileowner**

Now use self.webView instead of webView.

Also check if url has refernce before providing to nsurlrequest. as url u provide is www.google.com and uiwebview doenot recognize it so add 'http://www.google.com'

Now to load image in webView refer [this](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited) link.

Comment: Ok so I'm using the storyboard not the xib... so the fileowner is just the viewController itself right?

Thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;
```

//Create a URL object.

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
```

//URL Requst Object

```
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

//Load the request in the UIWebView.

```
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: your's [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];  My  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

Answer (score -1):

> If you're using a storyboard, the file owner is still there but it's
>   called View Controller. So to link the UIWebView in the storyboard to
>   the UIWebView outlet, you hold down control, then click and drag a
>   line from the View Controller to the Web View. This is all in the
>   'View Controller Scene' panel to the left of the storyboard.
>
> Note that when you first create your project from the Single View
>   Application template, there's no need to leave the 'Use Storyboard'
>   checkbox ticked. You might find it easier to follow these older
>   tutorials if you don't use a storyboard.
>
> By the way, another important checkbox, just under 'Use Storyboard',
>   is 'Use Automatic Reference Counting'. This is a great feature, but if
>   you have it turned on while you're following the tutorial you've
>   linked to, you'll need to skip the part where he releases the webView
>   instance variable.

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158556/